# userInteractionEnabled UIImageView works strangely

Tags: iphone

I create a UIImageView as below

```
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"military_male_target_001.png"];

imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10);

imageView.alpha = 0.5;
```

and I have

```
   - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {...}
```

in my view controller.

so far so good, the image is displayed on screen and respond to touch down event correctly which means touchesEnded method is invoked when I click inside the image.

but if I add

```
imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES
```

then touchesEnded method won't be invoked when I click inside the image.
but it is still invoked when I click outside the image.

can anyone tell me how userInteractionEnabled works?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it was not invoked is because you gave `imageView` permission to capture touches. The `imageView` will now get the touch event and not forward it on. There is no need to set `userInteractionEnabled` to `YES` unless you plan on creating a custom `UIImageView` that handles the touch event.

[Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> New image view objects are configured to disregard user events by
>   default. If you want to handle events in a custom subclass of
>   UIImageView, you must explicitly change the value of the
>   userInteractionEnabled property to YES after initializing the object.

Comment: thank you. I thought the event will be passed to parent finally.